# iOS Push notifications on iP6s

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, iphone-6

The app pushes push notifications to a user on the iPhone 4/5. However on the iPhone 6s, that same user doesn't get push notifications. The iPhone 6s does have settings applied to allow notiffcations on the device and through the app.
Any ideas as to why this could be occurring?

Comment: Verify that you are using the correct Push Token for same user in different devices.

Comment: are you register your device in APNS

Answer (score 0):

You must check:-

1- Your certifications for PushNotification in development and production.

2- Your provision profiles for development and production .

3- Generate PEM files for development and production.

4- Send to your server your correct device token.

5- In server used the correct PEM file and correct device token to send 
notification.

6- Check your device setting to allow PushNotification for your APP.

I hope I help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your iPhone 6 may have iOS 8 or later version.

At didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you have to register for push notification like below.

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *)
{

    if application.respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications")
    {

        let types:UIUserNotificationType = ([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])

        let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

}
else{
        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
}
```